# ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, backend

I have an error in my code and I am getting the following message: "ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }". Does anyone know what this error means and how I can fix it?
I'm using next 13 and trying to send data to a database in mongodb in a post query.
This is my code:

```
export async function POST (req, res) {
  const { nombre, apellido, id, age, direc, cell, email, pass, confirmPass } = req.body

  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      nombre,
      apellido,
      id,
      age,
      direc,
      cell,
      email,
      pass,
      confirmPass
    })

    const savedUser = await newUser.save()
    console.log(savedUser)

    const responseBody = { body: savedUser }
    const response = new Response(responseBody, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response({ status: 500 }, { error: error.message })
  }
}
```

I use thunderClient to make requestsa and the response is:
`[object Object]`

I've tried json.parse and json.stringify, setting headers and req.on

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your issue

```
const body = await request.json();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are you are not parsing the data well
Have you tried using body-parser?

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but it's not compatible with nexjs apparently

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to get the images from FormData then use this...

```js
const images = await req.formData();

//the formData will be your formData name which you send it from frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

req.json() works indeed, as opposed to JSON.parse(), for example. Yet this method does not exists on their own NextApiRequest, so that TypeScript throws an error.